# ffmpeg: how to encoded video using AMD VCE h265 + encoded the 2nd audio stream as AAC + burn-in the 2nd subtitle stream?

Tags: ffmpeg

As above. Thanks in advance!

PS. I'm on Windows.

---

This is the stream information as retrieved by ffprobe.

```
Program 1
Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream #0:2[0x1101]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Stream #0:3[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
Stream #0:4[0x1201]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090)
```

I tried these commands as a start (got them by putting together various info from various guides and ffmpeg documentation)

```
//works but selects all audio and no subtitle (no warnings or error)
.\ffmpeg.exe -i my-video.m2ts -c:v hevc_amf -rc cqp -c:a libfdk_aac -map 0:a:1 my-video.mkv

//trying to select audio stream but getting warnings (see below)
.\ffmpeg.exe -i my-video.m2ts -c:v hevc_amf -rc cqp -qp_i 25 -qp_p 25 -c:a libfdk_aac -map 0:a:1 my-video.mkv
```

This is the warning for the 2nd command.

```
[out#0/matroska @ 0000011e505deec0] Codec AVOption rc (Bit rate control mode) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[out#0/matroska @ 0000011e505deec0] Codec AVOption qp_i (quantization parameter for I-frame) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
[out#0/matroska @ 0000011e505deec0] Codec AVOption qp_p (quantization parameter for P-frame) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
```